# Plot PDF of log-normal distribution

Tags: matlab, probability, gaussian, probability-density

I'm using the [`randn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) function to generate a Gaussian random variable `x1` with mean 0 and variance 1. After generating `x1`, I generate another Gaussian random variable `x` with mean *m* and variance *σ*<sup>2</sup>, that is: `x = m + sqrt(σ)·x1`.

I want to create a [log-normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) random variable `y = ex` and plot its PDF. I think I can use the histogram function to do this:

```
N = 10^5;          %// sample
x1 = randn(N,1);
m = 0;             %// mean of x1
sigma = 1;         %// variance of x1
x = m + sigma.*x1; %// create x
y = exp(x); 
figure;
hist(y);
```

and here is the diagram I get:

[image: diagram]

I think that my result is wrong but I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [lognormal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution) can have a very long tail (i.e., even for large `y` the `prob(y) > 0` and not vanishing.
If you want to compare your pdf plot to those of e.g., the [wiki web page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution), you will need to ignore the tail.

```
bins = linspace(0,5,500);
n = hist( y, bins );
bar( bins(1:end-1), n(1:end-1)/N ); axis([0 bins(end-1) 0 1]); % discard last bin that has the "tail"
```